# Why is this struct sort crashing my program?

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

```
void sortAlphabetically(int listLength, contactInfo* arrayOfStructs)
{
    contactType temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arrayOfStructs[i].contactName, arrayOfStructs[i+1].contactName) > 0)
        {
                     temp = arrayOfStructs[i];    //swapping entire struct
                     arrayOfStructs[i] = arrayOfStructs[i+1];
                     arrayOfStructs[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error is your program crashing with, exactly?

Comment: Better question: why are you doing this instead of using `std::sort`?

Comment: @maxpm program.exe has stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression is invalid when `i == (listLength-1)` (assuming that `listLength` is a count of the number of elements in `arrayOfStructs`):

```
arrayOfStructs[i+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate up to `listLength - 1` only, or check that you're not at the last element before referencing `arrayOfStructs[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are indexing off the bound of the array:

`arrayOfStructs[i+1]`

I assume that `listLength` is the length of the list, meaning that it is one more than the last element of the list. Your for conditional of `i < listLength` keeps i within bounds, but not i+1.

That may, or may not, cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the following lines:

```
arrayOfStructs[i] = arrayOfStructs[i+1];
arrayOfStructs[i+1] = temp;
```

More specifically, the `i+1` part.  If your `for` loop runs from zero to `listLength - 1`, on the last iteration you will try to access one element past the actual range.

You can use `i < listLength - 1` to fix the problem, or just use an `if` statement inside the loop.  Changing the condition is probably better practice.